# Could not find gem squlite x64 ming32

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to download the Rails Dev Bundle and the rails server will not deploy. I am totally new to coding still learning. I keep getting this error
Could not find gem squlite x64 ming32 in any of the gem sources in your gem file.

Comment: You're probably going to have to give us a bit more to go off of. For starters, what does the `Gemfile` look like in your source directory?

Answer (score 0):

First try to install ridk and then use this commands

For ridk installation take help from here : https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/wiki/The-ridk-tool

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
gem install sqlite3
bundle install
```